# Google Doubleclick blank ads in homepage

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

I am owner of the website legiaodosherois.com.br and I am having issues after starting my first paid campaign with Google Doubleclick for Publishers. All my ad blocks are set for Adsense fallback and it was working pretty well until two days ago when all my ad blocks started to get empty only at homepage, and running fine in all the other pages. I tried to use the debug console by appending the ?google_force_console=1 at my homepage url but just by adding this piece of query string it already makes the ads shows up, so to reproduce my error you must access http://www.legiaodosherois.com.br/?google_force_console=1 and then access http://www.legiaodosherois.com.br/

I couldn't see any problems by checking this debug data, and Google says that the Ad Units are tagged correctly. What can I do?

**UPDATE:** I just have found that some specific pages such as http://www.legiaodosherois.com.br/2013/vazam-videos-com-as-primeiras-cenas-de-guardioes-da-galaxia.html also aren't displaying any ads!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English,
Vinicius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because some of my posts received a false positive flag from Adsense bot which forbid these pages to show ads. As they were also being shown in the homepage, it was also forbid to show ads. After cleaning them up, it started to work fine!